# convert factor variable into date

Tags: r, date

Suppose I have a variable as x with in the data frame z, which is a factor, but I want it to convert into date.

```
x <- factor(c("17.05.2016","19.05.2016","42472","42481"))
y <- 1:4
z <- data.frame(x,y)
z
```

I tried with the following code but I am getting the result partially correct.Could you please help me with this problem.

```
z$x1 = tryCatch({
z$x = as.Date(z$x ,origin = "1899-12-30")
},error = function(e){
z$x =as.Date(z$x, "%d.%M.%Y")
})
z
```

Comment: I tried but its not working. Its giving me the partially correct result as before!

Comment: How do you convert `42472` as `Date` ? and what is your expected output?

Comment: as.Date(42472 ,origin = "1899-12-30")
this will give you the result as "2016-04-12"

Comment: and `as.Date("17.05.2016", format = "%d.%m.%Y")` would give you `[1] "2016-05-17"`

Answer (score 2):

It works but it's not a trycatch

```
z$x1 <- as.Date(z$x, format="%d.%m.%Y")
z$x1[is.na(z$x1)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(z$x[is.na(z$x1)])) ,origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot CClaire for your help! It works accurately.